# How to Run Python Scripts (using Notepad++)

Tags: python, notepad++

I recently started following [this tutorial](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2blibtcod) on how to make a roguelike with Python. I have the first part of the code written(posted below) that draws and lets you control the player, but I'm not sure how exactly to run this and test it out. Also, I have Python installed, and I'm using Notepad++. Can someone help to figure out how to run my .py scripts?

Comment: On the command line type: `python myscript.py` (assuming python is in your *PATH*).

Comment: http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_Python%2Blibtcod,_extras#A_neat_Python_shortcut_for_Notepad.2B.2B

Answer (score 3):

Download the plugin PyNPP it will help with development in Notepad ++ haven't played with it too much though. Has options to customize your run options.
Has a shortcut as well to launch quickly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work, kinda... It runs the script, but I get this message: "libtcod 1.5.1  SDL: cannot load terminal.png   'Press any key to continue...'". I'm not sure what this means. Can somebody help me figure this out? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As the first comment says, type `python myscript.py` into the commandline.

It may be worth familiarising yourself with command line before trying your hand at programming; it's not particularly hard, and learning it all at once will be easier than learning the bits and pieces you need as they come up.

Comment: Actually, it turns out an image was missing from the folder, so it wouldn't run. Now I got it. Thanks for the replies everyone!